# Improving our algorithm with SQLite vs storing everything in memory

Tags: sql, c, algorithm, sqlite

**The problem**...I’m trying to figure out a way to make our algorithm faster.

**Our algorithm**...is written in C and runs on an embedded Linux system with little memory and a lackluster CPU. The entire algorithm makes heavy use of 2d arrays and stores them all in memory. At a high level, the algorithm’s input data, which is a single array of 250 doubles (0.01234, 0.02532….0.1286), is compared to a larger 2d array, which is 20k+ rows x 250 doubles.  The input data is compared against the 20k+ rows using a `for loop`. For each iteration, the algorithm performs computations and stores those results in memory.

I’m not an embedded software developer, I am a cloud developer that uses databases (Postgres, mainly). Our embedded software doesn’t make use of any databases and, since that is what I know, I thought I’d look into SQLite.

**My approach**...applying what I know about databases, I'd go about it this way:  I would have a single table with 6 columns: id, array, computation_1, computation_2, computation_3, and computation_4.  I’d store all 20k+ rows in this table with the computation_* columns initially defaulted to null. Then I’d have the algorithm loop through each entry and update the values for each computation_* column accordingly.  For graphical purposes, the table would look like this:

[image]

Storing arrays in a database doesn't seem like a good fit so I don't immediately understand if there is a benefit to doing this. But, it seems like it would replace the extensive use of malloc()/calloc() we have baked into the algorithm.

**My question is**...can SQLite help speed up our algorithm if I use it in the way I've described?  Since I don’t know how much benefit this would provide, if any, I thought I’d ask the experts here on SO before going down this path. If it will (or won't) provide an improvement, I'd like to know why from a technical standpoint so that I can learn.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think SQLite can store arrays. You should normalize it with each array element in its own row in another table, with a foreign key referring to this table.

Comment: You've not explained the purpose of storing 20K elements (lots of doubles) nor the purpose of their associated computed values... Without seeing the efficiency of the algorithm or knowing its purpose, one is left to observe that the generality of a relational database is likely overkill for dealing with a single table...

Comment: You talking about using SQLite as an in-memory database? (not external storage) You mention "little memory". Do you have the memory budget to be able to afford this increased usage? You haven't suggested any reason why SQLite might speed things up despite the added the CPU and memory loading. The limited information you provided sounds like this may be a simple operation, in which case improving the algorithm might be better. Possibly alter the algorithm to reduce or avoid the "extensive use of malloc()/calloc()"?  Or you could try and measure.

Comment: From the very little information given, I don't see how using a database can speed things up. Likely, any speed improvement will come from improving the algorithm that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 3):

As you have described it so far, SQLite won't help you.

A relational database stores data into tables with various indexes and so on.  When it receives SQL, it compiles it into a bytecode program, and then it runs that bytecode program in an interpreter against those tables.  You can learn more about SQLite's bytecode from https://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html.

This has a lot of overhead compared to native data structures in a low-level language. In my experience the difference is up to several orders of magnitude.

Why, then, would anyone use a database?  It is because you'd have to write a lot of potentially buggy code to match it.  Doubly so if you've got multiple users at the same time.  Furthermore the database query optimizer is able to find efficient plans for computing complex joins that are orders of magnitude more efficient than what most programmers produce on their own.

So a database is not a recipe for doing arbitrary calculations more efficiently.  But if you can describe what you are doing in SQL (particularly if it involves joins), the database may be able to find a much more efficient calculation than the one you're currently performing.

Even in that case, squeezing performance out of a low-end embedded system is a case where it may be worth figuring out what a database would do, and then writing code to do that directly.